# Appending a Combo box (including all its options) with Unique id Attributes using only Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have created a **combo box** with **options** (Bohol, Boracay, and Cebu-Mactan). Everytime I click the **button**, another **combo box** should appear with the same **options**.

```js
function addActivity(){

        var locationText = document.createTextNode("Location:")
        document.getElementById("activity-div").appendChild(locationText);

        var locationSelect = document.createElement("SELECT");
        locationSelect.setAttribute("id","location-sel");
        var locationOption1 = document.createElement("OPTION");
        locationOption1.setAttribute("id","boholLoc")
        var locationOption2 = document.createElement("OPTION");
        locationOption2.setAttribute("id","boracayLoc")
        var locationOption3 = document.createElement("OPTION");
        locationOption3.setAttribute("id","mactanCebuLoc")
        var locationOptionText1 = document.createTextNode("Bohol");
        var locationOptionText2 = document.createTextNode("Boracay");
        var locationOptionText3 = document.createTextNode("Cebu-Mactan");
        document.getElementById("activity-div").appendChild(locationSelect);
        document.getElementById("location-sel").appendChild(locationOption1);
        document.getElementById("location-sel").appendChild(locationOption2);
        document.getElementById("location-sel").appendChild(locationOption3);
        document.getElementById("boholLoc").appendChild(locationOptionText1);
        document.getElementById("boracayLoc").appendChild(locationOptionText2);
        document.getElementById("mactanCebuLoc").appendChild(locationOptionText3);

      }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="activity-div">
      Location:<br>
      <select class="locationSel" name="location" id="location" value="">
        <option value="bohol">Bohol</option>
        <option value="boracay">Boracay</option>
        <option value="cebu_mactan">Cebu-Mactan</option>
      </select><br>
      <span id="myText"></span>
    <button onclick="addActivity()">Add</button><br>
  </body>
```

Turns out, when I click the **button** more than once, the child will append on the same **combo box**. I know it has something to do with the `setAttribute("id","value")`. How do I make my **id**s dynamic? Or is there a shorter way to append the whole **combo box** with unique **id**s?

Comment: First of all, what are these IDs _needed_ for? (Beginners often act like an ID was the only way to select an element, but of course there’s countless other and often better ways.)

Comment: Yes. Indeed, I use ID as a way to select an element. :D

Comment: And later on when I implement php for my database, I will use the same concept to get a unique value. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with jquery you can easily insert options into combo box like this

```js
/**
function addActivity(){
         insertACombo();
        // here are the items that goes to the combo box
        // {'id': 'bohol', 'value': 'Bohol'},{'id': 'boracay', 'value': 'Boracay'},{'id': 'cebu_mactan', 'value': 'Cebu-Mactan'}
        var items = [];
        
        var index = 0;
        var values = $.map($('#location option'), function(ele) {
           items.push({'id': ele.value + (++index), 'value': ele.text});
           return ;
        });
        
        $('#combo2').append(function(){
          var output = '<option>select</option>';
                    $.each(items, function (key, value) {
                        output += '<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.value + '</option>';
                    });
                    return output;
        });
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
}
function addItemsToTheSameCombo(){
        // here are the items that goes to the combo box
        // {'id': 'bohol', 'value': 'Bohol'},{'id': 'boracay', 'value': 'Boracay'},{'id': 'cebu_mactan', 'value': 'Cebu-Mactan'}
        var items = [];
        
        var index = 0;
        var values = $.map($('#location option'), function(ele) {
           items.push({'id': ele.value + (++index), 'value': ele.text});
           return ;
        });
        
        $('#location').empty().append(function(){
          var output = '<option>select</option>';
                    $.each(items, function (key, value) {
                        output += '<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.value + '</option>';
                    });
                    return output;
        });
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
}



function insertACombo(){
  var sel = $('<select id="combo2">').appendTo('body');
}
*/
var i = 0;
function addNewComboWithSameItemsDiffIds(index){
    var sel = $('<select id="combo' + i + '">').appendTo('body');
    
    var items = [];
        
        var index = 0;
        var values = $.map($('#location option'), function(ele) {
           items.push({'id': ele.value + (++index), 'value': ele.text});
           return ;
        });
        
        $('#' + 'combo' + i).append(function(){
          var output = '<option>select</option>';
                    $.each(items, function (key, value) {
                        output += '<option value="' + value.id + i + '">' + value.value + '</option>';
                    });
                    return output;
        });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="activity-div">
      Location:<br>
      <select class="locationSel" name="location" id="location" value="">
       <option value="bohol">Bohol</option>
        <option value="boracay">Boracay</option>
        <option value="cebu_mactan">Cebu-Mactan</option>
      </select><br>
      <span id="myText"></span>
    <!--<button onclick="addActivity()">Insert a new combo and append same items with different ids </button><br><br>
    <button onclick="addItemsToTheSameCombo()">Insert items to the same combo with different ids</button><br><br> -->
    <button onclick='addNewComboWithSameItemsDiffIds(++i)'>Insert Items for each click to a new combo with different ids'</button>
  </body>
```

Comment: So I tried running this code. It doesn't add a select element. Instead, it adds an option to the same element.

Comment: do you want to add an element to the same combo box right ??

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to create a select element everytime I click the button. Each element should have the same options but unique ids.

Comment: so you want a new combo box with same options but different unique ids right ?

Comment: Everytime the button is clicked, another identical combo box should appear with a unique id. :)

Comment: Yes. Exactly :)

Comment: i have updated the answer please look if this solves

Comment: The updated codes has a similar  output to the one I posted. Options are added on the same combo box.

Comment: what ?? no.. !! there appends a new combo box into the same div and then add options from the previous combo box to the new combo box same text but different ids. that what you needed right ?

Comment: or you need to append the same items to the same combo box but with different ids ??

Comment: There new combo boxes don't have options. New options are added on the previous combo box.

Comment: Anyway, I found the answer. This is in pure javascript which means that the codes are quite long. However, you may still suggest a solution using jquery. :)

Comment: ok .. added two functions. one is responsible for adding items to a new combo with  unique ids. second one is responsible for adding same items to the same combo box with different unique ids.. hope this helps

Comment: and added another snippet to add a new combo for each click same option values but different ids

Comment: The design only needs one button. The ideal output is on the answer I provided. Do you have any idea on how to implement it in jquery?

Comment: actually it doesn't need 3 buttons. i kept those button for different scenarios. the label on the button say what the button does. commented out the rest buttons . so now its only the expected results is there

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. This is implemented using only **javascript**. I used `var counter` that increments every button click.

```js
var counter = 0;
function newLine(){
      var newLine = document.createElement("BR");
      document.getElementById("activity-div").appendChild(newLine);
    }

      function addActivity(){

        //Creates the "Location" text and append it to DIV
        var locationText = document.createTextNode("Location:")
        document.getElementById("activity-div").appendChild(locationText);
        newLine();

        //Creates a SELECT element, sets its ID attribute and appends it to DIV
        var locationSelect = document.createElement("SELECT");
        locationSelect.setAttribute("id","location-sel"+ counter);
        document.getElementById("activity-div").appendChild(locationSelect);
        newLine();

        //Creates an OPTION element, sets its ID attribute,appends it to SELECT, and puts TEXT label (BOHOL)
        var locationOption1 = document.createElement("OPTION");
        locationOption1.setAttribute("id","boholOption"+ counter);
        document.getElementById("location-sel"+ counter).appendChild(locationOption1);
        var locationOptionText1 = document.createTextNode("Bohol");
        document.getElementById("boholOption"+ counter).appendChild(locationOptionText1);

        //Creates an OPTION element, sets its ID attribute,appends it to SELECT, and puts TEXT label (BORACAY)
        var locationOption2 = document.createElement("OPTION");
        locationOption2.setAttribute("id","boracayOption"+ counter);
        document.getElementById("location-sel"+ counter).appendChild(locationOption2);
        var locationOptionText2 = document.createTextNode("Boracay");
        document.getElementById("boracayOption"+ counter).appendChild(locationOptionText2);

        //Creates an OPTION element, sets its ID attribute,appends it to SELECT, and puts TEXT label (CEBU-MACTAN)
        var locationOption3 = document.createElement("OPTION");
        locationOption3.setAttribute("id","cebuMactanOption"+ counter);
        document.getElementById("location-sel"+ counter).appendChild(locationOption3);
        var locationOptionText3 = document.createTextNode("Cebu-Mactan");
        document.getElementById("cebuMactanOption"+ counter).appendChild(locationOptionText3);

        counter++;
      }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="activity-div">
      
      Location:<br>
      <select class="locationSel" name="location" id="location" value="">
        <option value="bohol">Bohol</option>
        <option value="boracay">Boracay</option>
        <option value="cebu_mactan" >Cebu-Mactan</option>
      </select><br>

     </div>
     
  </body>
  <button onclick="addActivity()">Add Activity</button><br>
```